# PlasticSCM "you don't have permissions for operation view"

Tags: permissions, plasticscm

I had an error while connecting to a PlasticSCM Server.

The error says "you don't have permissions for operation view" but I'm permitted for the organization according to admin account.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that you are permitted for the organization, I guess that you mean your Plastic cloud organization. This message is not cloud organization related, but Plastic server related.

The error you are getting is when you try to connect to a Plastic server (your local repos or cloud repos). Please review the configured permissions of the server your are connecting to. 
From the GUI: "Repositories & Workspaces" --> Right-click a repo --> Rep server permissions.

This is a guide where we explain how to configure your server security:
https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/security/plastic-scm-version-control-security-guide.shtml

You are welcome to reach us:  support at codicesoftware dot com